# Complete the algorithm below to calculate and print the total sales for each product over the three month period in the format:

Tags: python

This has had me stuck for ages, can anyone help me? The stuff highlighted in bold is what I need assistance with, please try to stick with the format!

```
            Total for product 1: xx
            Total for product 2: xx
            etc [3]

sales = [
         [0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0]
        ]
totalsales = [0,0,0,0,0]

for product  = 0 to 4
    print("Sales for product", product + 1)
    for month = 0 TO 2
        sales[month][product]  =  input("Enter quantity for month ", month + 1,":") 
**insert code here**


    next month
next product
**insert code here**
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this yourself? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range will take a sequence from numbers, from 0 to N so:

```
for product in range(5):
    print("Sales for product", product + 1)
    for month in range(3):
        sales[month][product]  =  input("Enter quantity for month ", month + 1,":")
```

will iterate through the values of product from 0,1,2,3,4.